# Qlikview Macro VBScript to print pdf and email will not run consistently - Fails in email

Tags: macros, vbscript, pdf-generation, qlikview

I have been tearing my hair out over the last few days in trying to get this macro to work consistantly on the Windows scheduler.

Basically the workflow is as follows:

1) Windows Scheduler - Daily, uses Admin user credentials

2) Batch file - Reloads using /l

3) Reloads Qlikview application, which has triggers on post reload to save a pdf and email it using PDF Xchange and an html formatted e-mail to cover mobile.

I am getting such inconsistent behaviour that I cannot isolate the problem to any particular one thing.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  More often than not it fails on the Windows scheduler.  There is no error since QV has just thrown up the VBScript window in the hidden process.

I've been changing permissions, which helped me reach a level of inconsistent performance as opposed to no performance.

In addition, it appears that you cannot pass variables to the PDF Xchange printer.

The code in the macro is as follows:

```
sub ExportPDF
  printReportPDF "\\SGH-SRV-FPS1\S-Drive\eCommerce\Data Analyst\Reporting\Daily E-Commerce Report\E-Commerce Daily Report.pdf"

  ActiveDocument.GetApplication.Sleep 2000
  ActiveDocument.PrintReport "RP01", "PDF-XChange 3.0"
  ActiveDocument.GetApplication.Sleep 8000
end sub

Function printReportPDF(pdfOutputFile)
  Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WSHShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Tracker Software\PDF-XChange 3.0\OutputFile", pdfOutputFile, "REG_SZ"
  WSHShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Tracker Software\PDF-XChange 3.0\BypassSaveAs", "1", "REG_SZ"
  Set WSHShell = nothing
End function

Sub ExportEmail
  Dim strvDest 'as string
  strvDest = ActiveDocument.Variables("vDestination").GetContent().String 
  msgbox(strvDestination)

  Define report variables
  get the date as a serial for the filename output
  Export an Object

  Set obj = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("TX25")
  Set obj1 = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("TX17")
  Set obj2 = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("TX18")
  Set obj3 = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("TX15")
  Set obj5 = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("CH62")
  Set obj6 = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("TX16")
  Set obj8 = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("CH58")
  Set obj9 = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("TX31")
  Set obj10 = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.SheetObjects("CH69")
  msgbox("defined objects")

  obj.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\MainLogo.jpg"
  obj1.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\MainHeader.jpg"
  obj2.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\DateRange.jpg"
  obj3.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\SecondaryHeader.jpg"
  obj5.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\DailySiteDetail.jpg"
  obj6.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\SecondaryHeader2.jpg"
  obj8.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\WeeklySiteDetail.jpg" 
  obj9.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\SecondaryHeader3.jpg"
  obj10.ExportBitmapToFile "D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\WeeklySiteDetailLW.jpg" 
  msgbox("created objects")

  Dim objEmail
  Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2    Send the message using SMTP
  Const cdoAnonymous = 0        Do not authenticate
  Const cdoBasic = 1                basic (clear-text) authentication
  Const cdoNTLM = 2                  NTLM
  Const SMTPServer = "xxxx" ' changed for public consumption
  Const SMTPPort = 25                 ' Port number for SMTP
  Const SMTPTimeout = 120              ' Timeout for SMTP in seconds

  Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  Set objConf = objEmail.Configuration
  Set objFlds = objConf.Fields

  With objFlds
     ———————————————————————

     SMTP server details
     removed the html links down to this being my first post

    .Update
    ———————————————————————
  End With

  allow the passing of a variable from the load script to define the distribution list

  if len(strvDest) > 0 then
    msgbox("variable exists "&strvDest) 
    objEmail.To = strvDest
  else
    msgbox("variable does not exist") 
    objEmail.To = "xxxx" 'changed for public consumption
  end if

  objEmail.From = "xxxx" 'changed for public consumption
  objEmail.Subject = "Daily Reporting"

  HTML = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN"">" & chr(13) & chr(10)
  HTML = HTML & "<html>"
  HTML = HTML & "<head>"
  HTML = HTML & "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"">"
  HTML = HTML & "<title>Automated Emails!</title>"
  HTML = HTML & "</head>"
  HTML = HTML & "<body bgcolor=""#FFFFFF"">"

  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:MainLogo.jpg"" >"
  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:MainHeader.jpg"" >"
  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:DateRange.jpg"" >"
  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:SecondaryHeader.jpg"" >"
  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:DailySiteDetail.jpg"" >"
  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:SecondaryHeader2.jpg"" >"
  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:WeeklySiteDetail.jpg"" >"
  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:SecondaryHeader3.jpg"" >"
  HTML = HTML & "<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=""cid:WeeklySiteDetailLW.jpg"" >" 
  HTML = HTML & "<p>"
  HTML = HTML & "</p>"
  HTML = HTML & "</body>"
  HTML = HTML & "</html>"

  Set objBP = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\MainLogo.jpg", "MainLogo.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<MainLogo.jpg>"
  objBP.Fields.Update

  Set objBP1 = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\MainHeader.jpg", "MainHeader.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP1.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<MainHeader.jpg>"
  objBP1.Fields.Update

  Set objBP2 = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\DateRange.jpg", "DateRange.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP2.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<DateRange.jpg>"
  objBP2.Fields.Update

  Set objBP3 = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\SecondaryHeader.jpg", "SecondaryHeader.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP3.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<SecondaryHeader.jpg>"
  objBP3.Fields.Update

  Set objBP5 = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\DailySiteDetail.jpg", "DailySiteDetail.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP5.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<DailySiteDetail.jpg>"
  objBP5.Fields.Update

  Set objBP6 = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\SecondaryHeader2.jpg", "SecondaryHeader2.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP6.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<SecondaryHeader2.jpg>"
  objBP6.Fields.Update

  Set objBP8 = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\WeeklySiteDetail.jpg", "WeeklySiteDetail.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP8.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<WeeklySiteDetail.jpg>"
  objBP8.Fields.Update 

  Set objBP9 = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\SecondaryHeader3.jpg", "SecondaryHeader3.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP9.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<SecondaryHeader3.jpg>"
  objBP9.Fields.Update 

  Set objBP10 = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\WeeklySiteDetailLW.jpg", "WeeklySiteDetailLW.jpg", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBP10.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<WeeklySiteDetailLW.jpg>"
  objBP10.Fields.Update

  Set objBPDoc = objEmail.AddRelatedBodyPart("D:\QlikView\SGP-UDA\QVS_Source\UserApp\Qlikview Printing.pdf", "Qlikview Printing.pdf", CdoReferenceTypeName)
  objBPDoc.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<Qlikview Printing.pdf>"

  objBPDoc.Fields.Update
  objEmail.HTMLBody = HTML

  msgbox("attached objects")

  objEmail.Send

Set objFlds = Nothing
Set objConf = Nothing
Set objEmail = Nothing

ActiveDocument.Save
Application.Quit
```

End Sub

Comment: This is _way_ too much code for us to take, too domain specific and too poorly formatted for us to even grasp (I tried editing but gave up). Also, what is "inconsistent performance"?

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting of your code, but you should try to simplify it to the bare problem. Otherwise it will be dfficult to get help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot ask questions so I will try to give you an answer of the bat.

1. Firstly, does it reload manually from the QV Document? If yes then

   1. Then you are most probably using 2 differant usernames to reload, please make sure that the username used to reload via scheduler has permissions on every single file the VB is accessing.
2. Did you set the permissions on the VB side to the following:

   1. Requested Module Security = System Access
   2. Current Local Security = Allow system access

Lastly, On the General screen of the scheduled task, under security options at the bottom. Make sure "Run with highest privileges" is unticked, this sometimes causes issues.